# Interacting with contract via remix

Tags: remix, openzeppelin-contracts

I am following the code from 721 sample
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721

using remix, it compiles and deploys correctly to test network,
now my question is how to interact with the contract?

> gameItem.awardItem(playerAddress, "https://game.example/item-id-8u5h2m.json")
> Transaction successful. Transaction hash: 0x...
> Events emitted:
> - Transfer(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, playerAddress, 7)

Where should I type this command?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

After you compile and deploy the contract. Check the `Deployed Contracts` below the deploy button. You can access contracts functions from here:

[image]